# calling bootstrap modal show in ajax callback (safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Client does a request to rails controller heartbeat. Heartbeat respond with either success 200OK or error(unauthorised) 401. Client sends this request every 500 milliseconds.

I want to show bootstrap modal when error 401 occurs during ajax request. So inside I have put that modal('show') but bootstrap modal is getting triggered.

Here is code for adding bootstrap modal on document load.

```
$(function(){
  $('body').append('<div id="confirm-logout-modal" class="modal hide fade" style="display: none;"> \
                  <div class="modal-header"> \
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Logout</h3> \
                  </div> \
                  <div class="modal-body"> \
                    <p> \
                      <span class="modal-main-message">You have been logged out</span> \
                    </p> \
                  </div> \
                  <div class="modal-footer"> \
                    <button id="btn-confirm" class="btn btn-success">Okay</button> \
                  </div> \
                </div> \
               ');

  $('#btn-confirm').click(function(){
    $('#confirm-logout-modal').modal('hide');
    window.location.reload();
  });
});
```

Here is the code to show bootstrap on ajax error callback

```
function check_heartbeat(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/heartbeat',
    success: function(data){
      void(0);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      if(response.status == 401){
        clearInterval(heartbeat_id);
        $('#confirm-logout-modal').modal('show');;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

But the problem here is that its not showing modal popup when called from ajax error callback.
I have checked google chrome no error are there. Also I tried calling modal('show') console it does display the popup. Also I tried calling popup on document load then also modal popup works.

but only when called from ajax error callback it gives problem



More findings:
1. This problem happens only when rails server is started in production mode
2. Only backdrop is displayed but no modal. Modal is displayed after I click anywhere on backdrop. That time backdrop gets closed and modal popup is displayed.
3. This problem happens only on safari.
4. This problem happens only when safari tab is out of focus. If I am on the same tab and popup gets displayed. But If I am on the lets say 2nd tab and popup is being displayed on 1st tab. If I switch back to 1st tab then I only see backdrop.

Here is the JSFiddle code
http://jsfiddle.net/5y7725v5/
RUn the code and quickly switch to other tab. Wait for some time then switch back to original tab. See no popup. Now run the code and stay on same tab whola!! popup is displayed

Comment: you have extra `;` in your error callback's modal show.

Comment: Yeah there is. But it wont cause any problem.

Comment: There's clearly more going on in your code then you've presented. We'll have an easier time helping you if you post a jsfiddle or a plunker that demonstrates your exact issue. Strip out all the code that isn't relevant to your exact problem, make it fail in a reproducible environment, and others can help you debug your code.

Comment: I have found one more thing. This thing does not work only when rails server is started in production mode(here it minifies all the js code). In development mode it works correclty

Comment: Actually this is the relavant code thats it. Other code are related to other part of application which are irrelevant.

Comment: @skeggse I am not able to create a fiddle. Actually I have reproduct it on jsfiddle. But as content is too big its not saving up

Comment: @skeggse please check

Comment: It sounds like this is a bug with Safari (don't have a mac, so no way to check), but you should submit a bug report to the appropriate forum, which means you *need* to **make it reproducible**, meaning that you need to remove the dependency on your server, and simplify the code. A dependency on jQuery, while handy, complicates the issue, and makes it more difficult to diagnose. If you're using jsFiddle, you should go ahead and move all your code to jsFiddle itself, rather than referencing external files, and reduce your code there.

Answer (score -2):

It only show when the status **code is 401** that means unauthorized access

Try to check status code

Comment: I did send 401 from heartbeat controlller.